# set angular-ui-tinymce editor content after navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tinymce, angular-ui

I'm using angular-ui-tinymce (latest version 0.0.4, https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce/blob/master/src/tinymce.js).

I've encountered a problem I cannot solve.

On the first page load, content is loaded to the editor via ng-model.
Then I navigate to another state and then navigating back to state with the editor.
The value still exists on the scope (I've checked it) but the content doesn't appear in the editor for some reason I cant figure..

This is the the textarea with the directive as attribute:

```
<textarea rows="10" class="form-control" id="desc" ui-tinymce ng-model="valueFromScope"></textarea>
```

This changes happened after updating AngularJS from 1.5 to 1.2.1.
I thought it had something to do with ngSanitize but I'm not sure..

btw angular-sanitize and ngSanitize are included in the app.

Any advice?

**update**
It seems like ngModel.$render is not doing anything.

```
     ngModel.$render = function() {
        console.log(ngModel);
        tinyInstance = tinymce.get(attrs.id);

      if (tinyInstance) {

        tinyInstance.setContent(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
        updateView();
      }
    };
```

Nothing is printed out, not even undefined, this means ngModel.$render doesn't even run.
Any reasons for that?

**Update**

I don't think model.$render is related, from what I understand $render only executes on a programmatic change like actually editing the text and that works..

I still can't figure it out, sometimes the value is shown and sometimes not.

Comment: Some code? also - if you revert to 1.5 is the problem solved?

Comment: Reverting to 1.5 will cause too much errors on other parts of the code :{

Comment: I've added the html code in the post. The directive code is the default angular-ui-tinymce code.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be connected with sanitize since the code doesn't seem to be calling sanizite (the tinymce code).

Comment: @alonisser It seems like the directive is trying to set the editor value before the server responds with the value.
Its strange though, 1. because it worked before, 2. nothing changes in the editor when value is returned..

Comment: Looks like this bug (and the solution for the meantime) is described here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce/issues/49

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Problem Solved! - for now..**

Thanks to @alonisser I've found a solution.

From what I understand, the problem is occurring because something has changed in the prioritizing of angularjs directives.

read the following:
http://iwang.github.io/html/angular/angularjs/2013/11/04/ngmodel-render-cannot-be-overriden-in-angular-rc3.html

the simple fix is just to add priority definition to the directive

```
return {
  priority: 10,
  require: 'ngModel',
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the priority doesn't really solve the problem.

The only thing that worked for me was adding the following code before the `ngModel.$render = function()`

```js
    var stopWatch = scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue){
        if (!tinyInstance){
            tinyInstance = tinymce.get(attrs.id);
        }

        if (tinyInstance) {
            tinyInstance.setContent(newValue);
            stopWatch();
        }
    });
```